# How to deploy MERN app stack to Vercel/Netlify?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, netlify, vercel

I have project MERN stack and I want to deploy it to Vercel or Netlify. But when I deploy, it return 404: NOT_FOUND. My project has front end and backend as below (folder `client` is FE and folder `server` is BE).

[image: My project structure:]
[image: My project structure]